# spring boot pom.xml dependency version error

Tags: java, dependencies

I get the following error message, is it related to the denpendency version problems? THanks!

**Error message**

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector.detect(AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector.java:36)

The following method did not exist:

java.lang.annotation.Annotation org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.findAnnotationOnBean(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class, boolean)

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector, was loaded from the following location:

jar:file:/C:/Users/17che/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.7.0/spring-boot-2.7.0.jar!/org/springframework/boot/sql/init/dependency/AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory, is available from the following locations:

jar:file:/C:/Users/17che/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.9/spring-beans-5.3.9.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory: file:/C:/Users/17che/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.3.9/spring-beans-5.3.9.jar

**Action:**

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector and org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory

**pom.xml file**

```
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.7.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
            <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
               <version>5.3.9</version>
             </dependency>
```

**What I did:**

1. Add/change dependency
2. change the version in

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I had solve the problem, it's related to the version of jdk.